# Youtube search in Django -> manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: shell

Tags: python, django, youtube, oauth-2.0

[Youtube Code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#search_by_keyword)

If I use this code in IDLE - everything is ok, but when I use in Django project, i.e. run via `python manage.py shell` I see the next:

```
usage: manage.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME] [--noauth_local_webserver]
                 [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                 [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
                 [--max-results MAX_RESULTS]
manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: shell
```

I found that error occurs at line: `args = argparser.parse_args()`, but can not find how to fix that. Can anyone help?

**Edit:**
Once I launched shell, I call youtube_search(), but when interpreter executes line `args = argparser.parse_args()`, shell closes and I see the message above.

Comment: I think you are not calling the django manage.py script but something else. You should check your path settings.

Comment: @ger.s.brett I activate `virtualenv` (source /my/path/bin/activate), then `cd` to the folder with `manage.py`, then start `python manage.py shell` (I do it multiply times every day and the rest functions\classes work ok in this project :), then execute the `youtube search` function from the link above and I see the error above. Do I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't need to pass any arguments from command line to the function, I simply removed this:

```
  argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default="Google")
  argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)
  args = argparser.parse_args()
```

and pass arguments I need directly to the function:

```
search_queue = 'Jingle Bells'
max_results = 5
youtube_search(search_queue, max_results)
```

and make changes here:

```
def youtube_search(q, max_results):  # old version: def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=q,  # old version: q=options.q,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=max_results # old version: maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()
```